# Wordpress multiple user roles accessing on their information on one site

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress, multi-tenant

I intend to use Wordpress for the proof-of-concept of a cloud-based SaaS application I am building. My research into multi-tenancy and Wordpress only sheds insight into multiple sites sharing the same back-end, however, I would like to have a single site but the admin section should have different user roles that can only access their relevant content and dashboard to manage and or make requests to certain data. The dashboard will be different for 3 user roles so they can achieve they desired functions effectively.

Is it in any way possible for me to create new user role and assign the aforementioned rights to the specific rights (e.g. supplier, agent, tour operator)?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several plugins to add roles in wordpress. With them you will ba able to add roles and select wich action this role is allowed to do.

One of the most complete plugin for this is [Advanced Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager/)